# Hibernate freezing after Inserting into postgresql database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, c3p0

I'm building an application that reads information from a log file, and while reading the information it should save those data into a database. The information that I get from the log is a set of packages with some users added to the package, like bellow:

```
Package: (Total: 14, Used: 11)
                    CSHC, 11/11
                    CTQ8, 11/11
                    CTQ8, 11/11
```

Every time I end reading one package from the log I make a call to save the package into the database. The problem is that after saving the 4th package, the application freezes. And I have no clue why. Here is the code I am using.

Log process function:

```
boolean erasePack = false;
            Package pack = new Package();
            //System.out.println("Zerei? "+ petrelLicensesInUse);
            while (i < reportContent.size()){
                phrase = reportContent.get(i);
                if(erasePack){
                    pack = new Package();
                    erasePack = false;
                }


                if(phrase.contains(Constants.licenseUsageIdentifier)){
                    licenseUsage = true;
                    licenseUser = false;
                    licenseIssued = phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.totalLicenseAvailableId) + 10),phrase.indexOf(Constants.endLicensesIssued));
                    licenseUsed = phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.totalLicenseUsedId) + 12),phrase.indexOf(Constants.endLicensesUsed));
                    licenseIssuedNum = Integer.parseInt(licenseIssued);
                    licenseUsedNum = Integer.parseInt(licenseUsed);
                    licenseUsageList.add(phrase.replaceAll(";  Total of ", ", Used: ").replaceAll("Users of ", "")
                            .replaceAll(" licenses issued", "").replaceAll(" licenses in use", "").replaceAll("Total of", "Total:")
                            .replaceAll(" license in use", "").replaceAll(" license issued", "").replace("  ", " "));
                    if(licenseUsedNum != 0){
                        pack.setUsers(new ArrayList<PbrUser>());
                    }
                }

                if(phrase.contains(Constants.licenseUserIdentifier)){
                    licenseUsage = false;
                    licenseUser = true;
                    currPckg =  phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.licenseUserIdentifier) + 1),phrase.indexOf(Constants.licenseUserIdentifier + " "));
                    version = phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.version) + 3),phrase.indexOf(Constants.endVersion));
                    vendorDaemon = phrase.substring((phrase.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
                    pack.setNamePackage(currPckg);
                    pack.setVersion(version);
                    pack.setVendorDaemon(vendorDaemon);
                    pack.setNumberOfPackageLicenses(licenseIssuedNum);

                    //PackageController.create(pack);
                }


                if(licenseUser && phrase.contains(Constants.userStartDateId)){
                    //System.out.println(phrase.indexOf(Constants.userStartDateId));
                    currDate = transformDate(phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.userStartDateId)+Constants.userStartDateId.length()),phrase.length()));
                    //System.out.println(phrase.substring(Constants.spaceUntilUser +1,phrase.length()).indexOf(" "));
                    currName = phrase.substring(Constants.spaceUntilUser, (Constants.spaceUntilUser + phrase.substring(Constants.spaceUntilUser +1,phrase.length()).indexOf(" ")+1));
                    PbrUser pbrUser = new PbrUser(currName);
                    //PbrUserController.create(pbrUser);
                    reportMetadataList.add(new ReportMetadata(currName, currPckg, currDate));
                    if(licenseUsedNum != 0){
                        //PbrUser pbrUser = new PbrUser(currName);
                        pack.getUsers().add(pbrUser);
                    }
                    contSave++;
                }

                if(licenseUser && contSave == licenseUsedNum){
                    PackageController.create(pack);
                    contSave=0;
                    erasePack = true;
                }

                i++;
            }
```

Insertion code:

```
static protected void insert(Object object){
        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try {
          tx = session.beginTransaction();
          session.saveOrUpdate(object);
          tx.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            try {
    // Second try catch as the rollback could fail as well
              tx.rollback();
            } catch (HibernateException e1) {
              logger.debug("Error rolling back transaction");
            }
    // throw again the first exception
            throw e;
          }
        }
    }
```

Hibernate Session factory:

```
public class SessionFactoryUtil {

    /** The single instance of hibernate SessionFactory */
      private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
      private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

        /**
         * disable contructor to guaranty a single instance
         */
        private SessionFactoryUtil() {
        }

        static{
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry); 
      }

        public static SessionFactory getInstance() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

  /**
   * Opens a session and will not bind it to a session context
   * @return the session
   */
    public Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    /**
   * Returns a session from the session context. If there is no session in the context it opens a session,
   * stores it in the context and returns it.
     * This factory is intended to be used with a hibernate.cfg.xml
     * including the following property <property
     * name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> This would return
     * the current open session or if this does not exist, will create a new
     * session
     * 
     * @return the session
     */
    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

  /**
   * closes the session factory
   */
    public static void close(){
        if (sessionFactory != null)
            sessionFactory.close();
        sessionFactory = null;

    }
}
```

Hibernate cfg using C3p0 manage the pool of connections:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/licensecontrol</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="schlumberger.sis.licenseControl.model.PbrUser"/>
        <mapping class="schlumberger.sis.licenseControl.model.LicenseUsage"/>
        <mapping class="schlumberger.sis.licenseControl.model.LicenseUsagePK"/>
        <mapping class="schlumberger.sis.licenseControl.model.Package"/>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is the log file:

```
11:02:58,435 DEBUG GooGooStatementCache:215 - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache ----> CACHE HIT
11:02:58,435 DEBUG GooGooStatementCache:232 - checkoutStatement: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 5; checked out: 1; num connections: 1; num keys: 5
11:02:58,435 DEBUG GooGooStatementCache:307 - checkinStatement(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 5; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 5
11:02:58,435 DEBUG SQL:109 - 
    insert 
    into
        license_usage
        (id_package, id_user) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        license_usage
        (id_package, id_user) 
    values
        (?, ?)
11:02:58,435 DEBUG GooGooStatementCache:215 - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache ----> CACHE HIT
11:02:58,435 DEBUG GooGooStatementCache:232 - checkoutStatement: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 5; checked out: 1; num connections: 1; num keys: 5
11:02:58,435 DEBUG GooGooStatementCache:307 - checkinStatement(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 5; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 5
11:02:58,445  INFO StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener:275 - Session Metrics {
    1332957 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    25918978 nanoseconds spent preparing 17 JDBC statements;
    20022685 nanoseconds spent executing 17 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    43865256 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 6 entities and 1 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
11:02:58,445 DEBUG GooGooStatementCache:333 - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 5; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 5
11:02:58,445 DEBUG ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:236 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@c88b770: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@76faa8cc
11:02:58,445 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1747 - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@66cb8aa5 [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@2c9b93b9)
11:02:58,445 DEBUG GooGooStatementCache:333 - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 5; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 5
11:03:08,358 DEBUG ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:730 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@b4ace91 -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
```

Comment: Did you specify a primary key on your Package object?

Comment: Yes. 
@Id
@Column(unique=true,nullable=false,insertable=true, updatable=true)
 private String namePackage;